# How do we update a snowflake table with sorted values based on multiple columns without creating any new table

Tags: sorting, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a snowflake table as below. I want to sort the table by columns FILENAME and ROW_NUM and save the order in the table.

```
create OR REPLACE table TEST (
  ID VARCHAR,
  FILENAME VARCHAR,
  ROW_NUM NUMBER
);    

INSERT INTO TEST values ('1', 'abc', 2);
INSERT INTO TEST values ('2', 'abc', 3);
INSERT INTO TEST values ('3', 'abc', 1);
INSERT INTO TEST values ('4', 'xyz', 2);
INSERT INTO TEST values ('5', 'cbc', 1);
INSERT INTO TEST values ('6', 'xyz', 1);
```

I can use below query to display the sorted data but how do I save the sorted data in the database without creating any new table?

```
select * from TEST order by FILENAME, ROW_NUM;
```

Comment: Even with a new table, how would you expect the order of your data to be saved in any particular order?  Snowflake doesn't operate like that.  You should simply run the query with a sort as you have shown in your post.

Comment: Any idea why do you want the data to be sorted ? As neither Snowflake or any RDBMS stores the data sorted like in a view. You can create a VIEW which is ORDERED by the column that you want and see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL there's no inherent order to data, but there's a way to ask for data to be sorted physically for future uses: `CLUSTER BY`.

If the table is already created:

```sql
alter table t1 cluster by (FILENAME, ROW_NUM);
```

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/tables-clustering-keys.html#changing-the-clustering-key-for-a-table

Answer (score 0):

This answer uses create, but does not create a *new* table and is exactly what I was looking for clicking on this question.

**TL;DR:**

```
create OR REPLACE table TEST_TABLE as 
select * from TEST_TABLE order by  FILENAME, ID
```

**Long explanation:**

Use this if you do not want to use clustering, (e.g. the other solution) which will result in ongoing costs on the table as the cluster operation will keep running in the background to constantly keep the table sorted.

If that is not needed and only a single sort operation is needed, you can use the following example.

Note that if this is a big table, please plan ahead and select a warehouse appropriate for the size of the data. Otherwise, data will spell to local disk or even storage and you will end up paying more.

Another important note: This will recreate all partitions and you will pay for that storage for your retention period + fail safe.

I do not know if using clustering and then disabling it is cheaper from using this approach though.

**Full Example:**

```
create OR REPLACE table TEST_TABLE (
  ID VARCHAR,
  FILENAME VARCHAR,
  ROW_NUM NUMBER
);    

INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE values ('1', 'abc', 2);
INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE values ('2', 'abc', 3);
INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE values ('3', 'abc', 1);
INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE values ('4', 'xyz', 2);
INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE values ('5', 'cbc', 1);
INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE values ('6', 'xyz', 1);
INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE values ('7', 'abc', 3);
INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE values ('8', 'abc', 1);

select * from TEST_TABLE; 

create OR REPLACE table TEST_TABLE as 
select * from TEST_TABLE order by  FILENAME, ID
```